# How to find overlaps between subsets of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a large dataframe. Column A has website names, and Column B has all the IDs that visit that website. So - if a website has 100,000 visitors, there will be 100,000 rows for Website A, etc.

I want to get the overlap between all pairs of these websites - so, to understand how many people visit A&B, A&C, C&B, etc.

Sample data

```
project_name    ID
Website A   foo
Website A   bar
Website A   fizz
Website A   buzz
Website A   jam
Website B   fizz
Website B   buzz
Website B   bye
Website B   hello
Website B   jazz
Website B   down
```

The way I currently do is

- slice the dataframe by Website A;
- slice the dataframe by Website B;
- merge the two dataframes using the argument 'indicator' as True;
- count the 'left_only', 'right_only', and 'both' values in that Indicator column.

So in the above, I'd find that A has 5 visitors total, B has 6 visitors total, and there are 2 that visit both ('fizz' and 'buzz').

Code below

```
    #slice the df by the first specified project
    if name_one in project_list:
        df_one = df[(df.project_name==name_one)]
    else:
        raise KeyError(f"{name_one} is not a valid name")
        
    #slice the df by the second specified workspace or project
    if name_two in project_list:
        df_two = df[(df.project_name==name_two)] 
    else:
        raise KeyError(f"{name_two} is not a valid name")
    
    #merge the two using a suffix to indicate which belongs where
    merged_emails = (df_one.merge(df_two, 
                                  how='outer', 
                                  on='ID',
                                  indicator=True))
    
    both = len(merged_emails[merged_emails['_merge']=='both'])  
    one = len(merged_emails[merged_emails['_merge']=='left_only']) + both
    two = len(merged_emails[merged_emails['_merge']=='right_only']) + both    
    all = len(merged_emails.email_md5.unique())
    both_pc = round((both/all),4)
```

The problem is, with >70million rows and 1600 combinations, this takes a really long time.

Is there a faster way I can do this, please?

Comment: [`df.groupby(["A", "B"]).size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)? It's hard to tell what shape your data is in without a [mcve].

Comment: I need to analyse by different values in column A, not by different columns, if that makes sense. I'll add some sample data.

Comment: pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how="inner", on="viewers_unique_identifier")

Comment: You could sort by column B and then get the values of A according to the values in B in a single loop across all the A,B rows

Comment: @Girardi how would that work?

Comment: @travelsandbooks could you add some sample data?

Comment: I have done so and an expected outcome

Comment: I thought you wanted to get the pairs, as you explained in the beginning of the answer... but now with this update, I think sort won't do it promptly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total number of visitors to each website you can use [`GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```py
df.groupby("project_name").size()
# project_name
# Website A    5
# Website B    6
# dtype: int64
```

---

To find the `ID`s that they have in common, you can create `sets` from each of the  `project_name` groups and get the intersection of them all:

```py
gb = df.groupby("project_name")
set.intersection(*[set(group["ID"]) for name, group in gb])
# {'buzz', 'fizz'}
```

---

To do this as a pair-wise you'll need to generate all the pairs of `project_name` and subset the DataFrame by those:

```py
from itertools import combinations 

pairs = list(combinations(df["project_name"].unique(), 2))
# [('Website A', 'Website B')]

# then something like:
for subset in pairs:
    _df = df[df["project_name"].isin(subset)]
    # do operations on subset `_df`
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Could you explain what the * does in `set.intersection(*[set(group["ID"]) for name, group in gb])`?

Comment: `set.intersection` can accept  any number of arguments, the list comprehension `[…]` creates a list, but that list would only be one argument. The `*` unpacks the list into the function. In effect turning `set.intersection([s1, s2, s3])` into  `set.intersection(s1, s2, s3)`